# l have RelativeLayout Problem within different devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

the following is my recyclerView cell xml layout and screenshots of how it shows 
it shows aligned on some devices but shows on other devices not aligned and the list_consultation_section_two not shown and list_consultation_section_three is centered for no reason 
any ideas why this happens?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_certificate_item_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8dp">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_80dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_default_image_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/consultation_over_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_over_ar"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/consultation_status_online_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_online"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view" />
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/consultation_status_offline_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_offline"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/list_consultation_section_three"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_consultation_section_one">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_name_text_view"
                style="@style/subtitle1Style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:text="@string/dr"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_174c6c" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_specialty_text_view"
                style="@style/Body2Style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_name_text_view"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:text="استشارى اطفال"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_aaacad" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_consultation_date"
                style="@style/Body2Style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
                android:text="2/11/2019"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_aeb1b1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_consultation_messages_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/my_consultation_date"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_consultation_messages_number_bg"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                tools:text="0" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it works fine with Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 (API 28),OPPO A3fW (API 22)(totally different APIs versions) 
and doesn't work with Lenovo tab-7504x (API 24)

l know the solutions it works OK at all devices if l set fixed size for list_consultation_section_three
but l just wanna understand why? 
[image: this is the the required Layout and the layout what l get within some devices[![][1]]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make list_certificate_item_parent LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and give it weight, try this code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list_certificate_item_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5"
android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_150dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8dp">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_80dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user_default_image_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/consultation_over_image_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_over_ar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/consultation_status_online_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_online"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view" />
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/consultation_status_offline_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_consultation_offline"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/consultation_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/consultation_image_view" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_two"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/list_consultation_section_three"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_consultation_section_one">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_name_text_view"
            style="@style/subtitle1Style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:text="@string/dr"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_174c6c" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_specialty_text_view"
            style="@style/Body2Style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/my_consultation_doctor_name_text_view"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:text="استشارى اطفال"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_aaacad" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_consultation_section_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_consultation_date"
            style="@style/Body2Style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:text="2/11/2019"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_aeb1b1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_consultation_messages_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/my_consultation_date"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_consultation_messages_number_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:text="0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```